# How to get assisted Interaction break down by date?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm using this query

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/mcf?ids=ga%3A99364917&start-date=2016-11-05&end-date=2016-12-05&metrics=mcf%3AfirstInteractionConversions&dimensions=mcf%3Asource&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

To get first interaction analysis, but I get only the summary / total. I would like to get that number by date.

Meaning instead of getting: Facebook:100, Direct: 100

I would like to get

Facebook: 12/1/16:50,12/2/16:50

Direct: 12/1/16:30, 12/2/16:70

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just add `mcf:conversionDate` to the dimensions in your query. The returned rows will then be segmented by both MCF source and conversion date.